# parent controller function call depends of http method?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller base class that extends CI_Controller and then some other classes that extends my controller base class.

I would like to add some new features in the lowest hierarchy controller in the http post method case but when i submit the form the execution doesn't go through the child post method condition.

Is like the post method call will goes to previous controller class and not pass through the child function.

I have tried a function with only http get case and works.

**UPDATED**: sorry my error.

I found the problem, I have a redirect in parent post method, this is the reason why the execution does not go through child post method condition, ¿ are there any way dynamically to redirect in the child if exist a function that overrides the parent function or redirect in the parent if the method does not be overridden by any subclass ?

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function create() {
       if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
           //do things...

           redirect();
       }
       else
       {
            //do other things...
       }
}

class One_Controller extends MY_Controller {

  public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function create() {

    parent::create();

    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

      var_dump('POST');
      //do more things...
      redirect(); // here and not in the parent
    }
    else {
      var_dump('GET');
    }
  }
}
```

Anybody could help or guide me to the solution ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: use `$this->input->method() === 'post'` - it returns a lowercase version of your request method

Comment: still does not go through the child post method condition

Comment: You can probably use PHP's [Classes/Object Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php) and/or the [Relection api](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to determine relationships with regard to functions that override the parent. But that's a lot of business that, IMO, has a bad smell. I would like to know why the child `create()` method needs to call the parent `create()` method at all? From your example code it does not appear to be necessary.